# Is primefaces or jquery-ui has an component that allows multiselect and input value

Tags: jquery-ui, primefaces, multi-select

Is primefaces or jquery-ui has an component that allows multiselect and input value?
like follow image:
[image]

it allows user multiple select and input value.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces has selectmanycheckbox. see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectCheckboxMenu.jsf